# rest api url is wrong - undefinedrest/eu/V1/carts/

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have a M2.2 shop and I just upgrade it to M2.4
I have MagePlaza OneStepCheckout installed.
When I go to checkout, I get errors on my console regarding the requests to the api.
Somehow the Url is wrong and a "undefined" is added to the request.
The calls that are being done are:

- /onestepcheckout/**undefined**rest/eu/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id
- /onestepcheckout/**undefined**rest/eu/V1/carts/mine/set-payment-information
- /checkout/cart/**undefined**rest/eu/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods

My base url secure and non secure url are correct.

Did anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Thany you

Comment: what is the exact error in console

Comment: checkout/cart/undefinedrest/eu/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods 404 (Not Found)

Comment: undefinedrest : check in actual code this maybe some variable which is not able to set

Comment: I found the issue. 
In my case it was the module-theme/view/frontend/templates/pages/js/require_js.phtml, that was extendend and the var BASE_URL was deleted. That is why I have undefined in the url.
I hope this helps others that have same issue.

Comment: @mvistas Your comment helped at least one person :-)! Thanks so much!